# Spring Web Services and Spring Security Exception handling

Tags: exception, spring-security, spring-ws, wss4j

I am trying to think of an solution to cascade exceptions from Spring security as soap faults in Spring Web services.

We use Spring web services and perform authentication using `SimplePlainTextPasswordValidationCallbackHandler`. However all customized exceptions from within spring security get output as a "Invalid Soap Header" in the soap response. This is believe is the default behavior.

Any way we could perhaps override this behavior to cascade our customized exception to Spring WS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you need to implement an EndpointExceptionResolver as the handleValidationException method of the XwsSecurityInterceptor delegates the exception to this resolver as mentioned [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/security.html#security-xws-exception-handling) and [also here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/soap/security/AbstractWsSecurityInterceptor.html#handleValidationException(org.springframework.ws.soap.security.WsSecurityValidationException,%20org.springframework.ws.context.MessageContext)) . Or you can simply add SoapFaultMappingExceptionResolver to your applicationContext.xml like this:

```
<beans>
<bean id="exceptionResolver" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.SoapFaultMappingExceptionResolver">
    <property name="defaultFault" value="SERVER"/>
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <value>
            org.springframework.oxm.ValidationFailureException=CLIENT,Oops!Something went wrong
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

More Info on this [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/server.html#server-endpoint-exception-resolver)

Comment: Thanks for this information. I also realised that we were using XWSS security interceptor which would mask all exceptions as Security header errors no matter what configuration i did. Also we did not have the option to override the default behaviour of SpringPlainTextValidationCallbackHandler. I ended up using WSS4J which allowed me to customize the password handler behaviour and throw custom authentication exception. Using the exception resolver configuration you pointed out I was then able to cascade my custom authentication exceptions as soap faults !